# How do I troubleshoot my connection to the Google Adsense API

Tags: api, curl, adsense

I have a weird scenario where I'm not sure how to proceed.

With a contractor's help, I built a script that connects to the Google Adsense API and grabbed some data. It was working fine.

Then I changed some things and it stopped working. Oops! Now I get an error that says "Access not configured."

I went back to my original code, but it didn't work anymore either. Same error, "Access not configured."

My question is, how can I troubleshoot this?  I can't connect to the API with something like hurl.it, because my API key was set to match my web server.  Can I SSH into my web server and try and Curl manually to learn more?   Is there any documentation that dissects what's going on behind the scenes?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you give some more details on your setup, namely what programming language you're using and whether or not you are using the Google API client library for that language?

Also, by "AdSense API" I assume you mean the AdSense Management API at http://code.google.com/apis/adsense/management/overview.html ?

Comment: wow, just catching your response now Sergio. tool cool! Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Sergio's help, I solved this problem by creating a new Console project and starting from scratch. Then things worked fine again.

An example of the good ole "Nintendo Rule" - when in doubt, take the cartridge out of the system, blow it in, bang on things a little, try it again.

Shoulda tried that first!